# Can dump with Timescale be restored into new version of Timescale and updated there?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, timescaledb

I have a dump from Postgres 11 with  a Timescale 1.3.2 extension. I need to upgrade the extension to 1.7.4. Is it a working way to restore this dump into a db within a docker container with the Postgres11/Timescale_1.7.4 and update the extension inside it?

Previously I tried to restore it to PG11/TS_1.3.2 and to move the volume with the db data to PG11/TS_1.7.4 and then upgrade the extension. But I don’t know the right order in docker and the docker seems the fastest way. The way I described in the question above seems faster than what I tried but I don’t know if it will work

Answer (score 0):

No. you must update gradually as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/upgrades/)

Notes:

- [Docs: Version Matrix: Postgres vs. Timescale](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/upgrades/upgrade-pg/)
- you must manually keep track of which timescaledb version your dump has used: [feature request: get timescaledb-version of dump #2077](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/2077)
- also note, that the docker-images contain at last 5 versions: [ref#1425](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1425#issuecomment-638271592)